# Caching problem in TYPO3 extension controller while redirecting

Tags: caching, model-view-controller, typo3, extbase

When delete action is called, the record is deleted in the database but when it is redirected to listAction the value are still there until caches are flushed in the TYPO3 backend.

```php
public function listAction()
{
 // some code here
}

public function deleteAction()
{
  // some code here
  $this->redirect('list');     
}
```

Comment: If you want to get answers to your questions in the future please invest a little bit more time in formatting your code snippets properly and writing a readable description of your problem! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the redirect, include this:

```
$this->cacheService->clearPageCache([$pageIds]);
```

where the `$pageIds` is an array of the UID of the pages you need to be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

You can also define actions as non-cacheable actions in ext_localconf.php

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'TYPO3.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'Yourplugin',
    array(
        'Controller' => 'list, delete',
    ),
    // non-cacheable actions
    array(
        'Controller' => 'list, delete',
    )
);
```